# Pesky footer wont stay down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible through JavaScript or jQuery to set a minimum margin-top of a certain div relative to a another div? I have a site that changes pages through css animation and the footer will sometimes intermittently appear at the top of the page when the content is moving up.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Do you want the footer to be fixed to the bottom?

Comment: No I would like it so that it has a minimum margin top relative to another div

Comment: Can we get the link, for better understanding?

Comment: sure. www.mrliger.com. When you select different menu items you will see that the footer will shoot up for a split second sometimes. It might take you a few goes at switching menu items to replicate the issue

Comment: Why not hide it during the transition? I mean, you can hide() and show() on click...

Comment: ive tried that but it looks a little messy